# Informatica XML read error

Tags: xml-parsing, informatica

In my mapping we are using xml files as our source.Our issue is that while trying to execute our mapping using large xml files (i.e files larger than 300 MB) we are facing an error. The error message is 
**'Error [Invalid Document Structure] occured while parsing :[FATAL:Error at line1,char1 ']**
We have successfully executed our mapping with smaller files(size < 300 MB).

Is there any setting which can be changed to process such large files.If not, is there any workaround that can be done?

Comment: Are you 100% sure the file is valid? When you open it in IE or Firefox, is it displayed with no errors?

Comment: @ Marek   : yes no errors